# Callout mystery

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I have this function:

```
de[a_, x_] = -1 + (E^-x x^a)/((-a + x) Gamma[a, x]);
```

When I do

```
Plot[Callout[de[-7, x] // Re, "de", {10, .022}, {x, de[-7, x]} /. {x -> 4}], {x, 0, 20}]
```

I get the expected picture:

[image]

However, if I change `-7` to `-7.5`:

```
Plot[Callout[de[-7.5, x] // Re, "de", {10, .022}, {x, de[-7.5, x]} /. {x -> 4}], {x, 0, 20}]
```

then I get this disappointing result:

[image]

What is wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evaluate your callout:

```
Callout[de[-7.5,x] //Re, "de", {10, .022}, {x, de[-7.5,x]} /. {x->4}]
```

> Callout[-1 + Re[E^-x/(x^7.5 (7.5 + x) Gamma[-7.5, x])], "de", {10, 0.022}, {4,
>      0.0309208 + 0. I}]

Notice that the 4th argument is complex. This is why [`Callout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout) complains. So, use the real part:

```
Plot[
    Callout[de[-7.5,x] //Re, "de", {10, .022}, {x, Re @ de[-7.5,x]} /. {x->4}],
    {x, 0, 20}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I still don't understand why Mathematica complained about the argument `{10, .022}`, whereas the real problem was with another argument.

Comment: @IosifPinelis the complaint comes from the point specified not being a valid position for the placement of the callout. The system doesn’t know you’re intending to plot the real part of the expression, but it can assuredly & confidently tell you that “the point specified is not valid (though it could say something like ‘because the eqn to be placed upon is complex’)”